# Why does the electron withdrawing group increase acidic nature of carboxylic acids?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds

The doubt in my mind is that the electron withdrawing group is attached to the carbon atom of the carbonyl group and that carbon doesn't have any negative charge..the negative charge lies on oxygen atom so how does this electron withdrawing group pulls the electron from oxygen.?

Comment: The inductive effect decays very rapidly but it is not limited to a bond. Let quantitative assessment aside, it does not take much intuition to see that if the C atoms see less electron density in one side, it will attract some electron density from the other. If it would be a localized effect, then we would not even speak of inductive effects.

Answer (score 0):

The carbon atom attached to oxygen and electron withdrawing group(suppose halide) in an Acyl halide is strongly polarized and that is why they are very reactive and unstable.